# Why was my app rejected with "(REJECT) reserved policy group 'debug': not for production use"?

Tags: application-development

I uploaded my app to the store but received this error message:

found unexpected Exec with architecture 'all': ./qtcdevicedebughelper.py
 (REJECT) reserved policy group 'debug': not for production use

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Rejected because you uploaded a debug build of your app. Debug builds are made to test your app on devices and emulators; to upload to the store, you need to create a release build. The Publish tab in Ubuntu SDK lets you create a release build click package; increase your version number and then create a release build click package from the Publish tab and then upload it to successfully publish to the store.

This is probably because you uploaded the run-on-the-emulator click package, rather than using the Publish tab in Ubuntu SDK to make a proper release build and uploading that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply with a cmake built app like docviewer. I have no debug/release options available.